# Python Beginning in new line for each letter in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Let's say I have `a_string = "john"`

And I want it to be printed as

```
j

jo

joh

john
```

How could I do this using the loop? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Look into slicing.

Comment: @jalazbe I am sorry that I have not followed the rules. This is my first time using this website. I will read the post you gave me and follow those rules when I ask questions next time! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Johnwicc The main concern isn't rules, it's that stackoverflow shouldn't become a place where people get dumbed-down instead of getting smarter. Existing users usually encourage new users to try and think of solutions *instead of asking for solutions directly*. How that is expressed may be a little rough towards new users.

Answer (score 3):

```
text = "john"

for i,_ in enumerate(text):
    print(text[:i+1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to understand:

```
a_string = "john"
tmpStr=""
for c in a_string:
    tmpStr = tmpStr + c
    print(tmpStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(a_string)+1):
    print(a_string[0:i])
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the code does and how it works.